# Regular expression in Python for matching a pattern which may or may not have some parts

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

I have some rules which should satisfy for a string to be passed. Below are the rules:

1. Windows should be written as “Windows” and there shouldn’t be any trademark.
2. None of the words should be abbreviated as “win”,” wins”, “win7”, win8, “win10”. Language also in full form. No “eng”, it should be “English”.
3. 64bit, 32bit etc. should be mentioned before language and after “home” or “pro”.
4. There should not be “Microsoft” before Windows OS.
5. “Single language/ Multi language” should be before 64 bit and after “Home”.
6. In OS if its mentioned Windows 10 but Home and Pro is not mentioned. One of them must be mentioned.

Example: Windows 10 home Single Language/ Windows 10 pro/Windows 10 home Single Language 64 bit/ Windows 10 home Single Language 64 bit Spanish/ Windows 10 Pro Multi language 64 bit English, Spanish/ Windows 10 home, Single Language, 64 bit; these should pass.

But Windows 10/ Microsoft Windows 10/ Windows 10 home 64 bit Single Language/Windows 10 home, 64 bit, Single Language/ Windows 7 Home 64 bit multi language; these should not pass.

Note: The basic skeleteon to pass is:

```
Windows(space or comma)(10 or 7 or 8.1)(space or comma)(home or pro or professional)(space or comma)(single language or multi language)(space or comma)(64 bit or 32 bit)(space or comma)(language(s)).
```

Single/multi language may or maynot be there but if it is, it should be after home/pro and before 64/32 bit. 64/32 bit may or may not be there but it should be after single/multi language if its there.

This is what I came up with but its passing "Windows 10 home, 64 bit, Single Language" which should not happen:

```
filter_exp = r'(Windows)\s(10)\s(Home\b|Pro\b)([$,\s\b])?((\s)?(Single Language|Multi Language|\w)(\s(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)))?'
filter_exp1 = r'(Windows)\s(7|8.1)\s(Professional\b)([$,\s\b])?((\s)?(Single Language|Multi Language|\w)(\s(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)))?'
```

I ended up writing this and right now it seems to be working, but this might have few test cases failure:

```
filter_exp = r'(Windows)\s(10)\s(Home|Pro)([$,\s\b])?((\s)?(Single Language|Multi Language|\w)(\s(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)))?'
        #filter_exp = r'^(Windows)\s(10)\s(Home\b|Pro\b)([$,\s\b])?((\s)?(Single Language|Multi Language|\w)(\s(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)))?$'
        filter_exp1 = r'(Windows)\s(7|8.1)\s(Professional)([$,\s\b])?((\s)?(Single Language|Multi Language|\w)(\s(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)))?'
        filter_exp3= r'(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)[\s,.]*(Single Language|Multi Language)'
        filter_sym = u'Windows\N{REGISTERED SIGN}'
        if ((re.findall(filter_exp, elem) or re.findall(filter_exp1, elem)) and not re.findall(filter_sym, elem) and not re.findall(filter_exp3,elem) ):
           pass
        else:
            elem=' '.join(elem.split())
            elem=elem+'\n'
            ErrorList.append(elem)
```

Comment: Your example does not match, because of the lower case `home`. If I assume that's a typo, only `Windows 10 Home,` matches because `((\s)?(Single Language|Multi Language|\w)(\s(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)))?`can all be ignored due to the ? modifier. Also edited your post for better formatting.

Comment: Try editing the question so it may be more understandable for people here at StackOverflow. help people to help you

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard. But since they are not compulsory, i had to put that, but i understand why that won't work. That will only check the spellings if the order is already correct.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hi @halfer, I am sorry that i had to add "urgent". I have this deadline today.I wasn't aware of it until last night and i have been working under pressure to solve this and i am unable to come at a solution. This is my first question posted at stackoverflow, will keep this in mind later on. I am and would be really grateful if you or anybody could help me arrive at a solution. Thank you and apologies.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bernhard commented, `((\s)?(Single Language|Multi Language|\w)(\s(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)))?` can all be ignored due to the `?` modifier so `Windows 10 Home, 64 bit, Single Language` would match but only for the `Windows 10 Home` portion.

You should use `^` and `$` to make sure that the regex matches the entire string instead:

```
filter_exp = r'^(Windows)\s(10)\s(Home\b|Pro\b)([$,\s\b])?((\s)?(Single Language|Multi Language|\w)(\s(64bit|64-bit|32bit|32-bit)))?$'
```

Comment: The issue with this will be that, it will not accept "Windows 10 Home Single Language". The 64 bit part is not compulsory and neither is the sinngle language multi language part. But if they were to appear, they should follow the rules, i.e. 64bit after single/multi language and single/multi language after home/pro.

Answer (score 1):

```
match = re.search(r"^Windows[\s,]{1,2}(10(?![\s,]Professional)|7|8\.1)[\s,]{1,2}(Home|Pro|Professional)($)?(([\s,]{1,2})?(Single Language|Multi Language)([\s,]{1,2}((?:32|64|Quamtum-joke)[\s-]?bit))?)?;?( ([a-z']{4,}(?# 4 or more characters per language 'thai|dari|urdu')(, |\r))+)?(\r|\n|$)", subject, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    result = match.group()
else:
    result = ""
```

It's going to pass ::

> Windows, 10 Home Single Language 64bit 
> Windows, 10 Home Single
>   Language 64bit 
> Windows, 8.1 Professional Single Language 64bit
>   
> Windows, 10 Home, Single Language 64bit 
> Windows, 10 Home Single
>   Language 64bit 
> Windows 8.1 Professional, Multi Language, 64bit 
> Windows
>   8.1 Professional, Multi Language, 64bit 
> Windows, 10 home Single Language 
> Windows 10 home Single Language 
> Windows 10 pro 
> Windows 10
>   home Single Language 64 bit 
> Windows 10 home Single Language 64 bit
>   Spanish 
> Windows 10 Pro Multi language 64 bit English, Spanish 
> Windows
>   10 Pro Multi language 64 bit English, Spanish, Esperanto 
> Windows 10
>   home, Single Language, 64 bit;

********* Not pass :

> Windows 10 Home, 64 bit, Single Language 
> Windows 10 Microsoft Windows 10 Windows 10 home 64 bit Single Language 
> Windows 10 home, 64 bit, Single Language Windows 7 Home 64 bit multi language

To explain a bit:
    10(?![\s,]Professional)
"?!" Is a negative look ahead, it will match "10" but will look ahead of it and if it finds a Professional will fail the match.

If you need to introduce another rule, just tell me

Comment: Thanks a lot @YOGO, this worked like a charm.Could you please explain why "(?:32|64|Quamtum-joke)" has "Quamtum-joke"?

Comment: It’s just a joke, you can delete it. Enjoy.

Comment: Hey @YOGO, i need some help here! This should accept "Windows 10 Pro 64 bit English, Spanish, Esperanto". Multi language/Single language is not compulsory. Thanks a ton in advance. Please let me know if there's any confusion.

Comment: Hi Kirti, 
Here is the updated regex :


`^Windows[\s,]{1,2}(10(?![\s,]Professional)|7|8\.1)[\s,]{1,2}(Home|Pro|Professional)($)?(([\s,]{1,2})?(Single Language|Multi Language)?([\s,]{1,2}((?:32|64|Quamtum-joke)[\s-]?bit))?)?;?( ([a-z']{4,}(, |$))+)?($)`

Comment: Hey @YOGO,  its giving Up to Windows 10 Pro 64bit English\n", "Windows 10 Home 64bit English\n", "Windows 10 Pro 64bit English\n", "Windows 10 Pro 64bit English\n", "Windows 10 Pro 64bit English\n", "Features Windows 10 Pro and a 7th Gen Intel\u00ae Core\u2122 i3-7130U processor. Also includes 4GB of memory and a 500GB hard drive.\n", "Features Windows 10 Pro and an 8th Gen Intel\u00ae Core\u2122 i5-8250U\n", "Windows 10 Home 64bit English, French, Spanish\n", "Windows 10 Pro 64bit English, French, Spanish\n"] as error. but it shouldn't. sorry for reaching out after so long. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but that’s not help , it’s working for free. Sorry me.

Comment: Sorry @YOGO, that you felt that way! I guess that's the point to this portal that you could ask for help in solutions you are unable to get yourself. Thanks a ton for your help, it really got me near to the solution.

Comment: Sorry to you, but I think you are not asking for help or my concept of help is different. I think you should learn just a bit of regex and then it will be like help. Sorry, in no moment I wanted to be rude or disrespectful.